# OutboxMessage stays while nothing in OutboxState

Tags: masstransit

I have just published around 2170 messages and only 1 message is delivered while 1999 messages stays in `OutboxMessage` table.

I have checked `OutboxState` have 0 rows while `OutboxMessage` have 2169 rows.

I have checked the source code and found that `OutboxMessage` delivery is depends upon `OutboxState`.

The interesting  thing is that `OutboxMessage.OutboxId` is same for all 2169 rows. So, its look like the one row in `OutboxState` deleted after one delivery while the 2169 rows were inserting on way.

```
if (outboxState.Delivered.HasValue)
{
     await RemoveOutbox(dbContext, outboxState, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

     continueProcessing = 0;
}
else
     continueProcessing = await DeliverOutboxMessages(dbContext, outboxState, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Should I insert a new row in `OutboxState` with same OutboxId?

Comment: If you have a complete standalone repository that reproduces the behavior, create a [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions), otherwise you can contact [support](https://masstransit.io/support). Beyond that, no way this can be diagnosed on this site.

Comment: I think I got the issue. IPublishEndpoint instance should only be used for one transaction :facepalm

Comment: Make sure you're on the latest, as it should recognize the previous entities already committed and start a new outbox state after the previous transaction was committed. Always, always stay current with MassTransit.

Comment: Any breaking changes from 8.0.8 to latest 8.1.3?